# How to determine if this function is surjective?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I want to determine if this map/function is surjective:

$f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$

$f(x):\frac{x^3-\sqrt{\left|x\right|}}{3x^2+5+\sin\left(x^3+44\right)}$

I have tried proving the surjectivity by finding the inverse of $f(x)$ which didn't really work.

Comment: if you had an inverse, it would also prove injectivity which isn't true. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8shpsadd2b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The denominator is never zero so this function is continuous. What are the limits when $x$ tends to $\infty$ and to $-\infty$? What can you conclude from the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: What I now did was:

1) prove the function is continuous (the denominator is never zero as you said)
2) find the limit of the function when x tends to infinity and -infinity. (which will also be infinity and -infinity respectively)
3) and since the "range interval" (sorry, I study in German) is from [-infinity, infinity], according to the intermediate value theorem, the funtion takes every value in between, which also proves its surjectivity.

Do you agree? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.